# Props and onChildClick not working together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component "Item" and a child component "Order".

Item has a button that toggles whether "Order" is displayed. If book is displayed, it passes the fetched details as props to the Order component, as well as the function for toggling if its open or closed.

Before adding the props to "Order", the toggle worked perfectly. After adding the props, the prop-handling works as it should, but now the function doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

````
const Item = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState('');

    const [order, setOrder] = useState('');

    //Api call to get item

    const orderOpenClose = () => {
        setOrder(!order);
    };

    return (
        <>
                <div onClick={orderOpenClose}>
                    <Button text="Order"></Button>
                </div>
                {order ? <Order acc={item} onChildClick={orderOpenClose}/> : ""}
        </>
    )
}

const Order = (props, { onChildClick }) => {

    const { item } = props;

    return (
        <>
                
                <div onClick={onChildClick}>
                    x
                </div>
                <p>{item.title}</p>
    )
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `(props, { onChildClick })` is just not correct syntaxis, you can either destruct `props` or pass them as one object, but not both, so you can do either

```
const Book = ({acc, onChildClick })
```

or

```
const Book = (props) => {
 const { acc,onChildClick  } = props;
```

Comment: Yes, the last one worked for me, thank you very much!